# XMLHttpRequest does not execute in a Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, xmlhttprequest

**BackGround**

Currently working on a webpage which must work for both Mac OS and Windows.  Currently.  I have tested this code on IE and it works great, however when it comes to Mac OS it seems to now execute correctly as how it does with Windows.

**Problem**

I isolated the issue which is causing the problem in Mac OS.  This call out to a Sharepoint Doc lib, which in turn returns a byte array that I later create a Base64 string is causing the issue.  I have read the doc on the compatibility of XMLHttpRequest with Safari in the below and shows that it is compatible.  Not sure why it work so well in IE but does not work in Safari.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

**Code**

```
function GetImgB64(relativeUrl) {
var defferedVarVlalue = jQuery.Deferred();    
var b64Img;
$.when(TokenForSharePoint()).then(function (sharepointToken) {
        var url = "https://<tenant>.com/sites/<site>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + relativeUrl + "')/$value";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('GET', url, false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + sharepointToken);
        xmlhttp.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xmlhttp.onloadend = function (e) {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {                    
                var arr = new Uint8Array(this.response);
                var raw = '';
                var i, j, subArray, chunk = 5000;
                for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
                    subArray = arr.subarray(i, i + chunk);
                    raw += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, subArray);
                }
                b64Img = btoa(raw);
            }
            else {
                errorResults.Location = url;
                errorResults.ErrorCode = xmlhttp.status;
                errorResults.ErrorResponseText = xmlhttp.statusText;
                errorResults.ErrorMessage = "Unable to Load Image",
                ErrorHandler(errorResults);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.onerror = function (error) {
            MessageWindow();
        };
        xmlhttp.send();

    return defferedVarVlalue.resolve(b64Img);

});
return defferedVarVlalue.promise();
```

};

Answer (score 0):

also my script doesn't work with safari

Comment: in my script there is a xmlHTTP that call a php script that have to insert data into a database but it doesn't work with safari and i don't know why